# Printing from 1 to 100 in columns

Tags: c

Code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    if(i % 10 == 1)
        printf("\n%d", i);
    else printf("%4d",i);
}
```

Results:

```
(blank line)
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

How can I remove the first blank line without doing something like:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    if(i == 1 || i % 10 == 1)
        printf("\n%d", i);
    else printf("%4d",i);
}
```

And how can I 'indent' the columns? As the last column isn't properly arranged, and I have no idea how to fix it using printf's.

At last, sorry for wrinting '(blank line)' as I don't know how to make a blank line, and thanks for the help.

Comment: add single space to first line to fix indent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than printing a newline at the start of a line, print it at the end instead:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    printf("%4d",i);
    if (i % 10 == 0)
        printf("\n");
}
```

This prints each number in a 4 character field, then prints a newline if the last number is divisible by 10.

Output:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

Comment: The only problem I have with indexing any loop from `1` is it is not applicable to 99% of the time you will want to use column output -- with arrays. It's fine and you nailed what the OP was looking for, but `array[i]` won't work for `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The style is strange, a newline doesn't belong at the start of a string literal. A printf call should print the line and then output a newline if necessary:

```
"\nBad style"

"Good style\n"
```

To print the values correctly, change the logic. Always print the values of `i`, and then check if `i` is divisible by 10, and print the newline if it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    printf("%*d%c", (i % 10 == 1)? 0 : (i == 2) ? 4 : 3, i, (i % 10) ? ' ' : '\n');
```

Comment: It must be the phase of the moon that causes the juvenile behavior. I like the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have always done something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i && i % 10 == 0) putchar ('\n');
        printf ("%4d", i + 1);
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

You can also you separate format strings to accomplish the same thing:

```
char *fmt  = "%4d",
     *fmtn = "%4d\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    printf ((i+1) % 10 == 0 ? fmtn : fmt, i + 1);
putchar ('\n');
```

(*note:* in both cases the loop is indexed from `0` to accommodate indexing arrays)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arraycols
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```